# How to get the webview's vertical scroll postion while scrolling

Tags: javascript, android, webview, scroll, android-webview

I'm making some sort of book reader in webView. I have used the JavaScript, which dynamically creates the `<img>` tags via for loop. Look at the code's for loop, and every img tag is loaded with a different image from the URL.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
            "Loading Book...!", "Please Wait");

    String htnlString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style = \"text-align:center\"><script>var out = '';for (var counter = 1; counter <= 100; counter++){    out += '<img src=\"http://shiaislamicbooks.com/books_snaps/UR335/'+counter+'.jpg\"alt=\"Page No:'+counter+'\" width=\"100%\" />';}document.write(out);</script></body></html>";

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Completed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

    });

    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htnlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
}
```

Look at the `htnlString`:

- Now I want to display a book pages information in a textView. This means, while scrolling the webview the textView should update the txtPage.
- the `scrollTo(x,y)` is some how useful but I want the scroll listener for the webview.

Answer (score 1):

```
WebView webview;
yPos = webview.getScrollY();
xPos=webview.getScrollX();
```

Comment: i need this on scroll event of webview ??

Comment: it is better to put it onTouchEvent of webview.